# Making 2 divs float:right with one under the other

Tags: css, html, floating

I don't know how to better express my title so I'll explain here. I got a HTML/CSS page with 3 divs.

The first one, `div.presentation`, has no floating rule. I want to make menus at its right.

So I got two others divs, `div.login` and `div.categories`. They both have `float: right;` and `clear: both;`.

I want something like that :

```
 --------------------------------------     ------------------
|div.presentation                      |   |div.login         |  
|                                      |   |                  |
|                                      |   |                  |
|                                      |   |                  |
|                                      |    ------------------
|                                      |
|                                      |    ------------------
|                                      |   |div.categories    |
|                                      |   |                  |
|                                      |   |                  |
|                                      |   |                  |
 --------------------------------------     ------------------
```

But `div.login` and `div.categories` are aside each other. Floating rules worked perfectly when `div.categories` did not exist.

I have what I want when I put a `<div style="height:100px"></div>` between `div.login` and `div.categories`, but I'm sure we can do better. It's too based on luck.

Those 3 divs are `display:inline-block`.

Any idea ? Thanks a lot.

**EDIT** http://jsfiddle.net/7nJp9/1/

Comment: Why not just put the login and categories div in one div and float that div right?

Comment: Hey Jason can u plz share ur jsfiddle link??

Comment: When I do that, login and categories div are overlapped.

Comment: I meant, apply the float stuff to the new div and remove them from the original two divs.

Comment: That's what I did but they still vertically overlapped. 

http://jsfiddle.net/7nJp9/1/ (Thanks Ankit, I forgot !)

Comment: I've modified your css code from the jsfiddle and posted as an answer below. I've commented the areas I've modified. Biggest one was the position absolute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified your css:

```
body {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #e6f0ff;
}

header.beta {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  background: #fff7e0;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  color: #444443;
}

header.logo {
  width: 90%;
  height: 125px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border: 1px dotted grey;
}

nav.tabs {
  display: none;
}

div.presentation, div.login, div.categories {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div.right {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
}

div.presentation {
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}

div.login, div.categories {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}

div.login header, div.presentation header, div.categories header {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #0a97e2;
  padding: 3px 15px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; 
}

div.login section, div.presentation section, div.categories section {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

div.login section p, div.presentation section p {
  /* changed this */
  margin: 0px 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
}

div.login section input {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* added this */
div.categories ul {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
}
```

Comment: Oh, so I needed to remove position:absolute and add a margin-top: O, thanks a lot it works !

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div class="left">
 <div class="presentation"></div>
</div>
<div class="right">
 <div class="login"></div>
 <div class="categories"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left { 
  float: left; 
}
.right { 
  float: right; 
}
```

Comment: It works even without the float:left, but now my login and categories div are vertically overlapped ! Check out http://jsfiddle.net/7nJp9/1/

Thanks for trying to help

Comment: Add min-height: 130px; to div.login and toy with the height

Comment: I belive putting all of the elements you want to float somewhere in a parrent element is a batter solution, ie your sollution. The other tricks are basically hacks withc will end up breaking the CSS at some point and you wouldn't know where to start looking.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="width:430px; height:430px; border:1px solid;">
    <div style="width:230px; height:100%; float:left; background:#000;"></div>
    <div style="width:180px; float:right; height:150px; border:1px solid;  margin-top:20px;  margin-right:10px;"></div>
    <div style="width:180px; float:right; height:150px; margin-top:20px; margin-right:10px; border:1px solid;"></div
</div>
```

Try this one